# Forcing Cache refresh after deploying new code

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5, browser-cache, http-caching

We are running into issue where our clients are served stale js, css files after  code is deployed. We are using IIS as our webserver and our code is in ASP.Net 4.5. I did some research and figured out that ETag in conjunction with Cache-control should work. As I understand ETag is automatically generated by web server based on datetime stamp of file so I ran following steps to see why the system is not sending the latest version of js and css files.

1. Navigated to my website to a webpage let's call is demo.aspx.(Now assuming that demo.aspx contains reference to a.js, b.js and c.css)
2. Verified that a.js, b.js and c.css file were requested by browser and webserver delivered those files after I hard refersh a page(Ctrl + F5) on my website.
3. Clicked on some other webpage
4. Went to webserve and manually updated files (a.js, b.js and c.css to update datetime stamp of those files)
5. Navigated to demo.aspx again.
6. This time I see only request made to demo.aspx but not to any of the resource file (a.js, b.js and c.css).

I am at loss as to why .js files are not requested when I access my demo.aspx page.

Also, Is there any easy way to force client browsers to download latest version of .js and .css files every time I deploy code. Based on my research, I did find out that one way to do would be to rename .js and .css file. Please note that this soution won't work for us.

We do use update panel in our projects. Not sure if that has anything to do with browser not requesting js files second time

Answer (score 0):

A widely used trick is to add a query string parameter that is incremented with every new version of the `css` or `js` file.

Like `myScript.js?version=12`. When the the number changes the browser sees it as a new file and it's downloaded rather than retrieved from cache.

Just changing the timestamp by editing the file won't work, the browser does not get the timestamp from the server. You can try this by saving an image or file from the website, they all have the timestamp of when they were being downloaded.

Comment: Thanks @VDWWD for that suggestion. I have read about that on SO but this solution won't work for us.